# how to convert from a json object to a database table row (insert) using jackson and jdbc?

Tags: jackson, spring-jdbc

I have a json object that is desserialized like:

```java
TypeReference<HashMap<String, Object>> typeRef
    = new TypeReference<HashMap<String, Object>>() {};

HashMap<String, Object> map = objectMapper.readValue(json, typeRef);
```

Important to note: There is no java class to map (the types are only known by the database)

I'm able to obtain the types from the database schema:

```java
public static List<TableColumnTypeMap> getTableColumns(DataSource dataSource,
                                                       String schema,
                                                       String tableName) {
    try {
        return (List<TableColumnTypeMap>) JdbcUtils.extractDatabaseMetaData(dataSource,
                dbmd -> {
                    ResultSet rs = dbmd
                            .getColumns(null, schema, tableName, null);
                    List<TableColumnTypeMap> list = new ArrayList<>();
                    while (rs.next()) {

                        String columnName = rs.getString("COLUMN_NAME");
                        String typeName = rs.getString("TYPE_NAME");
                        int dataType = rs.getInt("DATA_TYPE");

                        TableColumnTypeMap tableColumnTypeMap = new TableColumnTypeMap()
                                .setColumnName(columnName)
                                .setColumnType(typeName)
                                .setSqlType(dataType);
                        list.add(tableColumnTypeMap);
                    }

                    return list;
                });
    }
    catch (MetaDataAccessException ex) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("get table list failed", ex);
    }
}
```

So I am able to know the type of each object in the map.

How do I tell jackson "Hey, this map item is this type" ?

Then I will be able to:

`jdbcTemplate.update("<insert statement>", objs);`

where `objs` is an Array of objects "stored" as objects but with correct type.

Answer (score 0):

I have converted all to String and got thru this method:

```
private Object getObject(TableColumnTypeMap tableCol, String val) {
    switch (tableCol.getSqlType()) {
        case Types.BIT:
        case Types.BOOLEAN:
            return Boolean.parseBoolean(val);
        case Types.DECIMAL:
        case Types.DOUBLE:
        case Types.FLOAT:
        case Types.NUMERIC:
        case Types.REAL:
            return new BigDecimal(val);
        case Types.BIGINT:
            return Long.parseLong(val);
        case Types.INTEGER:
            return Integer.parseInt(val);
        case Types.SMALLINT:
            return Short.parseShort(val);
        case Types.TINYINT:
            return Byte.parseByte(val);
        case Types.DATE:
            return java.sql.Date.valueOf(LocalDate.parse(val, DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE));
        case Types.TIMESTAMP:
            try {
                return Timestamp.valueOf(LocalDateTime.parse(val, DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE_TIME));
            }
            catch (DateTimeParseException e) {
                return java.sql.Date.valueOf(LocalDate.parse(val, DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE));
            }
        case Types.TIMESTAMP_WITH_TIMEZONE:
            return Timestamp.from(ZonedDateTime.parse(val, DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME).toInstant());
        default:
            return val;
    }
}
```

Observations:

- I use only those types;
- On json dates are formatted as iso dates;